# "Coroutine was never awaited" in simple concurrent code

Tags: python

I am new to Python concurrent programming. This is a very simple example that I have to deal with, but it's running into an error:

```
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = None

    async def parse(self, text):
        return text

async def call_parser(text):
    parser = Parser()
    parsed = await parser.parse(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_parser("test this routine")
```

It reports this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'call_parser' was never awaited
  call_parser("test this routine")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I can't add `async` to my main function, right? How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to `run` the coroutine:

```
asyncio.run(call_parser("test this routine"))
```

This gets the event loop and run the coroutine.

If your version of `asyncio` doesn't have `run` callable, you can do it in the old style:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(call_parser("test this routine"))
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.7. How to get asyncio?

Comment: @marlon `import asyncio`